# ClassCastException for configuration CGLIB proxy and org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Factory after upgrade Spring to 6.0.9 and Spring Boot to 3.0.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, cglib

In our project, after upgrade the SpringBoot from `3.0.4` to `3.0.9`, several of our tests started to fail on

```
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.buildProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:222)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:158)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.buildProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:517)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:464)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:369)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:318)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:434)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class our.project.RepositoryConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0 cannot be cast to class org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Factory (our.project.RepositoryConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0 and org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Factory are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.buildProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:213)
    ... 89 more
```

It's not bounded just to the `our.project.RepositoryConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration`. When I disable this configuration, then similar exception occurs on next configuration.

Another weird thing is that the test passes if only the single test class is called or if this class is executed first. Otherwise the ClassCastException ocurs.

We use TestNG for testing.

I tried to upgrade Spring to version 3.0.6 from 3.0.4 and Spring Boot to version 3.0.6 from 3.0.4 and I expect that all our current tests will pass. But for 34 tests of our ~ 2000 there is an exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: class our.project.RepositoryConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0 cannot be cast to class org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Factory (our.project.RepositoryConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0 and org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Factory are in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally. after almost of week of investigations,  I managed to isolate the sinner. Solr 8.2.1 causes this issue. With Solr 8.2.0 it works with  Solr 8.2.1 there is class cast exception for spring proxies.

Hard to believe that this is related.

Comment: Maybe shou should not have waited for 2 weeks before asking the question here.  Moreover, if you want an explanation of why the problem occurred, simply post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, then someone can take a look, reproduce it and find out for you what the root cause of the problem is and whether your workaround actually addresses the root cause of just covers it up until next time you get the same problem in another situation.

Comment: Can you share the fix here?

Comment: "After almost a week of investigations" - typical Spring.. I've even posted a comment in that regards to almost the same issue reported on GitHub.. (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31908#issuecomment-1902621528) they have minimized the comment in order to censore it out.. But it's true, Spring sux.. It is easy to setup some demo projects, but when it comes to maintanence or solving complex issues, you realize that its cost is higher than the benefits it's trying to provide ..Annotation-driven meta programing, alias welcome back to 00's, Spring is a joke